# Testing Facebook integration prior to approval

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I'd like to test a mobile app in development, which will use the Facebook API to log a user in and read mutual friends. However, from what I can tell, I can't use the API to log in a user unless the app is verified, but to verify the app,  the review team will "need to test and verify [my] Facebook integration."

Considering (per my impression), I wouldn't be able to test my own integration before submitting it, I'm rather confused. I feel like this is a "chicken and the egg" thing, so I imagine I'm not understanding how this works correctly.

Could anyone please explain or point me to any resources that will? I've been searching endlessly on how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean verified by Apple or Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to wait for its approval. You'll need to create the app on [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) and then you'll be able to use the Apple ID you'll be given to test it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So logging in through Facebook etc will (in theory) work prior to approval by Facebook's review team? I'm also developing for Android using Phonegap, if that's in some way relevant.

Comment: I only recall having to wait for Facebook's approval when using actions. Nothing special was needed to login

Comment: Apparently I neglected to mention that I need to pull mutual friends, too. I assume that's something for which I'd need approval?

Comment: Nope, when a user logs into your app and you request no additional permissions, the app will have access to only the user's public profile and also their friend list. No need even to ask for permissions

Comment: anyways you can send it for approval and change it later, even if testing

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for all the info.