# How do I test Facebook integration (retrieving a user's friendlists) before the app is approved?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've tried requesting permissions in my app, but the FB login popup contains a red error message saying that the app must be approved before it can request the user_friendlists permission.

How is this possible if the review/approval process requires a working test version of the app?

The problem is similar to this question: [Testing Facebook integration prior to approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780694/testing-facebook-integration-prior-to-approval) except mine is a website so the solution there doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The user logging into facebook from the app must be listed under the Tester roles in the app settings.  The tester also has to be a profile other than the administrator, which you probably are if you created the app, and it must have a profile picture and be friends with the administrator.